# PHP selenium find parent sibiling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below code and I want find second `td` value. How can I select text with `<br/>` in it?

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top" style="width: 85px">
    <span class="fieldtext">Address:</span>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    Shaftesbury House, 1st floor
    <br/>20 Tylney Road
    <br/>Bromley
    <br/>Greater London
    <br/>BR1 2RL
    <br/>United Kingdom
    <br/>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;" rowspan="2" />
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the `td` element by the `Address:` label defined previously, you can use the [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//td[span = 'Address:']/following-sibling::td
```

Then, after locating the element, call `getText()` method:

```
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//td[span = 'Address:']/following-sibling::td"))->getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :-

```
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//tr/td[2]'))->getText();
```

Hope it helps....:)